# loopbackjs "inq" for array of objects

Tags: loopbackjs

I have array of object field in loopback model.Want to use "inq" option to filter by day.Already have seen docs but those are for array of strings,not the one Iam finding.

```
weekDays": [
        {
          "day": "Monday",
          "startTime": "03:45",
          "endTime": "04:23"
        },
        {
          "day": "Wednesday",
          "startTime": "03:23",
          "endTime": "12:23"
        }
```

Syntax for array of string is like {weekDays:{inq:[]}} ,help what modification has to be done here.

Comment: have you tried `where : { day: { inq: ['Monday'] } } ` on your weekDays model ?

Comment: @Daniel   Thanks for your response.WeekDays is not model,its one of the property of my model.

Comment: can you try like `{'weekDays.day' : {$in: ["Monday"]}}` as its work in robo 3T like

`db.getCollection('user').find({'weekDays.day' : {$in: ["Monday"]}})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use two way in `MongoDB`

1.Simple `find` method

```
db.getCollection('user').find({'weekDays.day' : {$in: ["Monday"]}})
```

2.By using aggregate

```
db.getCollection('user').aggregate([
        {$unwind:'$weekDays'},
        {$match : {'weekDays.day' : {$in : ['Monday']}}},
         { "$group": {
        "_id": "$id",
         "weekDays" : { "$push": "$weekDays" },
        }},
    ])
```

3.aggregate in `loopback`

```
var collection = ModelName.getDataSource().connector.collection("myCollection");

collection.aggregate(
  [ 
    { $unwind:'$weekDays' },
    { $match : {'weekDays.day' : {$in : ['Monday']}}},
    { "$group": { "_id": "$id", "weekDays" : { "$push": "$weekDays" }}},
  ],
  function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
    } else {
      console.lod(data)
      });
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I am using loopback-connector-composer for database.