# MongoDb: query on array field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've this object on `reference` collection:

```
> db.reference.find().pretty();
{
    "_id" : "Ref1",
    "metadata" : {
        "values" : [
            {
                "hola" : "adeu"
            },
            {
                "departament" : [
                    {
                        "ambit" : "just",
                        "name" : "ts"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-09-22T08:37:08.989Z"),
    "_class" : "com.Reference"
}
```

I need to get document where `metadata.values` has an object `{hola: "adeu"}`.

I've tried without any luck:

```
> db.reference.find({metadata: {values: {hola: "adeu"}}});
> db.reference.find({metadata: {values: [{hola: "adeu"}]}});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try with db.reference.find({metadata: {values: { $elemMatch: {hola: "adeu"}}}});

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: You can try : `db.getCollection('reference').find({"metadata.values.hola" :  "adeu"});`,

Also This lik help you with aggregate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404430/loopbackjs-inq-for-array-of-objects/52423085?noredirect=1#comment91791757_52423085

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
db.getCollection('reference').find({"metadata.values" : { "$in" : [{"hola" : "adeu"}] }});
```

You can also do an elemMatch like this, when you want it for a single object:

```
db.getCollection('reference').find({"metadata.values" : { "$elemMatch" : {"hola" : "adeu"} }})
```